# Custom WordPress registration form issue

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have made a registration form in wordpress but when i press the registration button, the form doesn't gets registered

```html
<form id="flyer-registration-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="full-name">Full Name:</label>

    <input type="text" id="full-name" name="full_name" required>

    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>

    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>

    <label for="flying-date">Flying Date:</label>

    <input type="date" id="flying-date" name="flying_date" required>

    <label for="profile-picture">Profile Picture:</label>

    <input type="file" id="profile-picture" name="profile_picture" accept="image/*" required>

    <label for="flying-from-country">Flying From Country:</label>

    <select id="flying-from-country" name="flying_from_country" required>

        <option value="">Select Country</option>

        <option value="america">America</option>

        <option value="india">India</option>

    </select>

    <label for="flying-from-state">Flying From State:</label>

    <select id="flying-from-state" name="flying_from_state" required>

        <option value="">Select State</option>

    </select>

    <label for="flying-from-district">Flying From District:</label>

    <select id="flying-from-district" name="flying_from_district" required>

        <option value="">Select District</option>

    </select>

    <label for="flying-to-country">Flying To Country:</label>

    <select id="flying-to-country" name="flying_to_country" required>

        <option value="">Select Country</option>

        <option value="america">America</option>

        <option value="india">India</option>

    </select>

    <label for="flying-to-state">Flying To State:</label>

    <select id="flying-to-state" name="flying_to_state" required>

        <option value="">Select State</option>

    </select>

    <label for="flying-to-district">Flying To District:</label>

    <select id="flying-to-district" name="flying_to_district" required>

        <option value="">Select District</option>

    </select>

    <button type="submit" id="register-button">Register</button>

</form>

<script>

const statesByCountry = {

    america: ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'],

    india: ['Andhra', 'Arunachal', 'Assam']

};

const districtsByState = {

    america: {

        alabama: ['Autauga', 'Baldwin', 'Barbour'],

        alaska: ['Anchorage', 'Juneau', 'Sitka'],

        arizona: ['Apache', 'Cochise', 'Coconino']

    },

    india: {

        andhra: ['Kakinada', 'Eluru', 'Kurnool'],

        arunachal: ['Anjaw', 'Kamle', 'Lohit'],

        assam: ['Barpeta', 'Cachar', 'Dhubri']

    }

};

const flyingFromCountryDropdown = document.getElementById('flying-from-country');

const flyingFromStateDropdown = document.getElementById('flying-from-state');

const flyingFromDistrictDropdown = document.getElementById('flying-from-district');

const flyingToCountryDropdown = document.getElementById('flying-to-country');

const flyingToStateDropdown = document.getElementById('flying-to-state');

const flyingToDistrictDropdown = document.getElementById('flying-to-district');

flyingFromCountryDropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {

    const selectedCountry = this.value;

    const selectedState = flyingFromStateDropdown.value;

    flyingFromStateDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select State</option>';

    flyingFromDistrictDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select District</option>';

    if (selectedCountry) {

        statesByCountry[selectedCountry].forEach(state => {

            const option = document.createElement('option');

            option.value = state.toLowerCase();

            option.textContent = state;

            flyingFromStateDropdown.appendChild(option);

        });

    }

});

flyingToCountryDropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {

    const selectedCountry = this.value;

    const selectedState = flyingToStateDropdown.value;

    flyingToStateDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select State</option>';

    flyingToDistrictDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select District</option>';

    if (selectedCountry) {

        statesByCountry[selectedCountry].forEach(state => {

            const option = document.createElement('option');

            option.value = state.toLowerCase();

            option.textContent = state;

            flyingToStateDropdown.appendChild(option);

        });

    }

});

flyingFromStateDropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {

    const selectedCountry = flyingFromCountryDropdown.value;

    const selectedState = this.value;

    flyingFromDistrictDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select District</option>';

    if (selectedCountry && selectedState) {

        districtsByState[selectedCountry][selectedState].forEach(district => {

            const option = document.createElement('option');

            option.value = district.toLowerCase();

            option.textContent = district;

            flyingFromDistrictDropdown.appendChild(option);

        });

    }

});

flyingToStateDropdown.addEventListener('change', function() {

    const selectedCountry = flyingToCountryDropdown.value;

    const selectedState = this.value;

    flyingToDistrictDropdown.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select District</option>';

    if (selectedCountry && selectedState) {

        districtsByState[selectedCountry][selectedState].forEach(district => {

            const option = document.createElement('option');

            option.value = district.toLowerCase();

            option.textContent = district;

            flyingToDistrictDropdown.appendChild(option);

        });

    }

});

document.getElementById('flyer-registration-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // Handle form submission here

});

</script>
```

I was expecting to get the form to get resgistered

Comment: Looks like you prevented the default form submission, but then forgot to actually implement the necessary part below that `// Handle form submission here` comment ...